# EditText: setting a background color for highlight, then removing it

Tags: android

I want to highlight the background of an EditText, a simple

```
editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
```

is fine for that purpose.

However, I can't find a way to exactly reverse this.

```
editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
```

and also

```
editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```

completely change the look of the control.
The `EditText` afterwards no longer looks like an `EditText` but either becomes a solid white rectangle, or disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple task but the pitfall lies in the fact that setting a background color also affects the style. Setting the background to a color, there's no way to set it back with the same method.

I found the solution to be

```
editText.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);
```

This works for me, afterwards the UI element looks and acts exactly the same as before.

Comment: "This is a very simple task but the pitfall lies in the fact that setting a background color also affects the style" -- the background of an `EditText` is not a color. It is a `StateListDrawable` backed by a series of 9-patch PNG files. Changing the background to any color (e.g., `RED`) will make the `EditText` no longer look like an `EditText`.